# Homogeneous oscillating magnetic field without conductor and current

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

As pointed out by [Induced electric field from homogeneous magnetic field in free space points in all directions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523392/induced-electric-field-from-homogeneous-magnetic-field-in-free-space-points-in-a), a current density must present if we impose a uniform and oscillating magnetic field.

However, current density doesn’t quite make sense to me if there is no charge or conductor in such a space. So, **if it’s a free space (no charge or current) while we still impose such an oscillating magnetic field, what would be physically happening?**

I am inclined to think it’s not physically possible. However, it also seems to me that we can approximate such a situation with a sufficiently large solenoid.  And it concerns me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> However, it also seems to me that we can approximate such a situation with a sufficiently large solenoid.

And that is correct. If the solenoid is long enough to be approximated by an infinitely long solenoid, then the solenoid can carry the current density needed to generate the time-oscillating uniform B field.

> if it’s a free space (no charge or current) while we still impose such an oscillating magnetic field, what would be physically happening?

> I am inclined to think it’s not physically possible.

Yes, it is not physically possible, as the link also explained, by carefully deriving. ProfRob's answer is really clear there, isn't it? What are you even asking?

Look, it is illegal for us to write down EM fields and charge-current densities that disagree with Maxwell's equations, no matter how often we handwave and approximate things that way.

Comment: The current density is only within the coils of the solenoids, but in order to satisfy the Maxwell’s equation locally at the center of the solenoid, there must be current density at center. But how does this current density exist in free space? And this solenoids with AC is physically possible.

Comment: You should have read the answer in the other post, and its commentary, carefully. The current density needed to get the uniform oscillating magnetic field is not unique.

Comment: For the solenoids case, even if it’s not unique, they must all at least implies there is non zero current density at the center. And that’s what my question is about.

Comment: You are just mistaken. You can have zero current density inside the solenoid. That is what I am telling you. If you do not trust it, work out the maths yourself.

Comment: You are right, time derivative of E is zero at the center as E is proportional to r and zero at the center. For other places off center, the curl of B is no longer zero and time derivative of E is also non zero.